# readonly field appearing automatically when i open in mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" required="" placeholder="Name" style="width:100%" readonly="">
.form-control[disabled], .form-control[readonly], fieldset[disabled]
```

this is showing when I open developer tools

please help me with that

I tried to remove that from CSS file but that linking automatically

Answer (score 0):

I don't clearly understand what you're asking for, because your input will be displayed in all cases, readonly is only there to prevent writing.